# Run python script using Pyrolite from java

Tags: java, python

I have a simple python script in my local machine, which returns a string. I want to run this script from java application and get the return value. I'm trying to do this using Pyrolite. I downloaded the jar files and added them to my java class path. But I'm not able to run the script.

I got the below sample code from readme.txt

```
NameServerProxy ns = NameServerProxy.locateNS(null);
PyroProxy remoteobject = new PyroProxy(ns.lookup("Your.Pyro.Object"));
Object result = remoteobject.call("pythonmethod", 42, "hello", new int[]{1,2,3});
String message = (String)result; // cast to the type that 'pythonmethod' returns
System.out.println("result message="+message);
remoteobject.close();
ns.close();
```

But this is not working for me. My system configuration is

> OS: Windows 8
>
> JDK: jdk1.7.0_51
>
> Python: 2.6

Please help me with this.

This is how I have edited the code:

```
        NameServerProxy ns = NameServerProxy.locateNS(null);
        PyroProxy remoteobject = new PyroProxy();
        Object result = remoteobject.call("C:\\trail1.py", null);
        String message = (String)result; // cast to the type that 'pythonmethod' returns
        System.out.println("result message="+message);
        remoteobject.close();
        ns.close();
```

Comment: what errors do you get?

Comment: @nafas: Connection refused: connect

Comment: it seems to me, that ur python is some sort of service. if its not the case, y don't u just use Process class?

Comment: @nafas: There are some python scripts which returns dictionary and I need to manipulate this dictionary in my java application. For such scenarios I don't know if process will help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not positive that I understand what you're trying to do.

If you carefully read the tutorial, you'll see that you can't use Pyrolite the way you are.  It specifies that you must have a python script running as a server, WITH a name server, where you must define some classes (for example `Your.Pyro.Object`).

Then you'll be able to call those objects you defined in that python script, but not the script itself.

To do what you want to do you'll need to call a function like C's `fork()`.  Then you're able to call an executable, and you don't need Pyrolite.

Comment: Somebody edited my answer, without my approval. That's the first and last time I answer something here, for sure.